# Automethod of range class failed

Tags: vba, filter, autofilter

Very simple code to filter a table based on the value of a specified cell:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim sCriteria As String

sCriteria = "*" & Range("C4").Value & "*"

ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=_sCriteria, Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

When I run it I get a automethod of range class failed error...I can not for the life of me work out why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you so much,

Rach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter
```

I'm not sure you can use `Range` on its own. You would likely have to specify what range you intend to apply the filter to, by using `Range("A1:O500")` or something to that effect (the range I just gave being only an example.)

---

**EDIT**: Problem solved by simply removing the Range part, thus making the line

```
   ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").AutoFilter
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. I tried adding a relevent range and it just did nothing, when i removed it the code suddenly worked! But...only if the cell (C4) is not selected!

Comment: So you have to type in the cell then select another cell and then if you press the button it works....so weird.

Comment: Possibly you were still in 'edit' mode? I don't think the code works if you can still see the insertion bar blinking, since the text wasn't 'validated' yet, and the code therefore can't take it into account.

Comment: Yes you're right...I think I might have to change it so it runs on enter. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem! (If you don't mind, I'd greatly appreciate if you could accept my post as answer to your question by clicking on the checkmark, since it then shows your question as solved. Welcome to StackOverflow!)